# Whenever i restart sails server session got expired how to save session in database?

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js, sails-mongo, connect-mongo

from past two days i am facing this problem. whenever i restart my sails server session got expired and all users got logged out.
Is there any way to overcome from this ? I have gone through the sails doc but not successful to save the session in database.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your problem if you really hope to get any help.

Comment: adapter: 'mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  db: 'sails',
  collection: 'sessions',

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: There seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3574) in `sails` that's preventing mongo session store from working as expected.

**EDIT2**: The documentation repository has been [updated](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/commit/d16dcb7b1bc72bcbd34fdec7fbada478542d5a92) and the website should be updated soon as well.

You need to use mongo-connect v0.8.2 if you're using node <=0.12.x, and mongo-connect >= v1.0.0 if you're using node >= v4.x

You will have to update your [sessions configuration](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session#?using-other-connectcompatible-session-stores)

To use mongo as a session store, install the `connect-mongo` package as a dependency

```
npm install connect-mongo
```

Then in `config/sessions.js`

```
module.exports.sessions = {
    adapter: 'mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    db: 'sails',
    collection: 'sessions',
};
```

Comment: I have gone through the sails doc but not successful to save the session in database. @elssar  
and need to tell u this they have mentioned wrong version of connect mongo

Comment: Thats odd, probably a typo in the docs. There is a version 0.8.2 available, does that work?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in sails that's preventing mongo sessions from working - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3574

Answer (score 0):

You can store session in redis. After restarting session is not cleared.

```
sails 0.11.2
redis-connect 1.4.7
```

In session.js

```
adapter: 'connect-redis'
```